# How can I convert this SAS datastep to oracle sql for a conditional counter column?

Tags: sql, plsql, sas

I apologize for the generalness of the question. I'm trying to create a column that groups rows together based on the time between the current and previous observation. The code below is code that I' wrote that works correctly in SAS. However because of the way that a data step runs vs how oracle sql runs I can't figure out how to do this in oracle sql. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
DATA GROUP;
SET LAG1;
BY CUSTOMER_KEY;

IF (TIME_BTW>5 OR TIME_BTW=.) THEN JOURNEY=0;
JOURNEY+1;
IF FIRST.CUSTOMER_KEY THEN GROUP=0;
IF JOURNEY=1 THEN GROUP+1;
RUN;
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are defining groups based on `time_btw`.  You seem to want an analytic function.  I think the code is like this:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when time_btw > 5 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customer_key order by ??) as grp
from t;
```

Note that in SQL (unlike SAS), tables represent *unordered* sets.  This means that you need a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Sorry, I've spent the last 20 minutes trying to format the sample data in a way that was readable but I can't get senseful solutions to work. This gets me almost there! For groups this is great. The only problem is that if there are multiple obs where time_btw is>5 then they all share the same grp number as well. I'm going to start experimenting with alterations to this and see what happens.